# Coffee and a movie with friends

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, story, geography

> The day after our wedding, me and my wife Becky met our friend Charlotte and her husband Alan for coffee and a movie.
>
> **Me:** Hi Charlotte! Hi Alan!
>   **Charlotte:** Hi! So, are you two finally married now?
>   **Me:** Yep! She said yes, and so did I!
>   **Charlotte:** Congratulations! We're so happy for you!
>   **Alan:** Yeah, congratulations! Are you planning a honeymoon?
>   **Becky:** Next week, yeah. But don't ask us where we're going. It's a big secret!
>   **Charlotte:** Ooh! Suspense!
>   **Alan:** Nice!
>   **Me:** We haven't told anyone. Not even my mother knows.
>
> (We have a cup of coffee while waiting for the film to start.)
>
> **Alan:** So I take it you didn't watch the opening ceremony last night, hehe.
>   **Me:** Haha, yeah. Didn't want to spend our wedding night watching Bush speak. I'm not so much into sports in any case.
>   **Alan:** Yeah, we didn't watch it either. It came on way too late in the night.
>   **Charlotte:** Should we maybe get going? We don't want to miss the start of the film.
>   **Alan:** Okay, could we get the check, please?
>   **Me:** I'll take it, Alan... No, wait. I think I left my purse in the car. Ahh!
>   **Alan:** Don't worry about it, I'll take care of it... Hmm, forty-five? How much is that? I still haven't gotten used to this money, haha.
>   **Becky:** Yeah, I still convert them in my head too.
>   **Alan:** You girls go ahead if you want, I'll catch up. Where are you parked?
>   **Becky:** Over there, just across the street. Looks like it's raining. We'll be in the car.

Where does this story take place? Looking for the name of the country.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are in

> The Netherlands.

This is because

> Watching Bush speak at an opening ceremony for sports would imply that the Olympics were on at the time...the only time a President Bush was in office for a US-hosted Olympics was in 2002. Also at the beginning of 2002, the Euro would have replaced the Dutch Gilder. The ceremony would have been late at night because it would have been 8 hours later in Holland than in Salt Lake City, Utah. Finally, “you” mention that you forgot your purse — stretching here implies you are a woman but you have a wife. In the EU, I believe the Netherlands legalized/recognized same-sex marriages starting in 2001, the only EU nation (I think) to do so before 2002.

Comment: That looks good. The way Alan addresses the other three at the end backs up your last point.

Comment: Yup, this is spot on. Well done!